# Using drupal_add_feed() in template.php gives warning errors

Tags: 7, theming, feeds

As soon as I add a call to [drupal_add_feed](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_feed/7) in my theme template.php file I get this warning:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback,   no array or string given in theme_get_registry() (line 277
>   of  /var/www/example.com/includes/theme.inc).

The feed (created by Views) is valid, and the code *works*, i.e. it does add the meta tag. But the warning is unacceptable, obviously.

Fix? Something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need instal Zen and STARTERKIT theme in (...sites\all\themes).Because STARTERKIT need Zen theme to work.

Comment: Thank you but I am not using the Zen theme (so I don't need the Zen starter kit).